# Is it possible to change the EC2 instance region?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to know if I can change the region of my EC2 instance?

The region I use is Ohio, the reason I decided to change is that I was studying AWS and I learned about latency. I don't really know if I'm sure what latency is, but I understand that my server is located in Ohio, and if my clients don't reside in Ohio, the time to download from the website may not be as fast as the download time for a person who lives in Ohio.

That said, most of my users are located in Brazil, so I need to know if it is a good alternative to change the Ohio region by São Paulo, due to the fact that most customers are in Brazil, which would make their lives more easy.

If it is possible to make this change, is it a very complex thing that I should really leave as it is? I'm just a curious beginner, with the goal of learning more

**Note:**
I also want to point out, I use AWS RDS, S3 and CloudFront, should I change anything in these services?

Comment: You should almost always use the region that is the closest to your / your Users location

Comment: @codeflush.dev That's good. São Paulo would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the EC2 instance's region. However, you can create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) from the instance and then copy that to the desired region. Then launch the instance in the new region from the AMI you created.

Similarly with RDS. While you cannot change the region, you can create a snapshot to S3 and restore that snapshot in the new region.

Comment: It sounds good. Could you tell me if `creating an image AMI for the instance and then copy it to the region` is the same as "backup"? I mean, everything I have in that instance will go to the new one in the other region, won't I have to install a web server or anything else?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-ami-copy-between-regions/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the link. I wish you success!

Comment: Always my pleasure :)